# Simulate keycode for all apps

Tags: android, keycode, simulate

I am using that function for simulating keycodes:

```
public static void simulateKey(final int KeyCode) {

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
                inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyCode);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception when sendKeyDownUpSync", e.toString());
            }
        }

    }.start();
}
```

But I want to use it for all apps. For example if application A simulates the some keycode on background it should work while application B on top.

Comment: Its impossible Im afraid. Every app works in its own sandbox.

Comment: But i can show toast messages or start intent from other app what is the difference?

Comment: The difference is who is in control.

Comment: I can start intent or show toast messages from Activity A which is paused while the Activity B on top

Comment: You can only interact with apps that are signed with your own key. That the reason why Robotium black box tests require a re-sign of external APK files (see https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Frobotium.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FRobotiumForBeginners.pdf&ei=tcojVa-UOsGvsQHtjYLACg&usg=AFQjCNGxQ9yW3AXVraiazdgNEz8qAz_TTw&sig2=TX8A6NBscmsb-W4xH4WW9A&bvm=bv.89947451,d.bGg).

Comment: Toasts don't interact with other applications. I'm not sure why they can do this, but I imagine it is possible for them for debugging purposes. And for the situation that an app, for some reason, needs a user's immediate attention.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, for good reasons. You don't want one person's app to just click on the buttons of another app. It might be clicking "publish my private pictures to all my contacts", for all you know...
Even without that, the layout of the targeted app might change with an update; it could be clicking a different button, or clicking on a place where there no longer is a button.

What you can do, is use an [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). By using Intents, it is up to the receiving app whether or not to take action. Also, an update of the layout will not change the reception of an Intent.
It is of course possible that the app that receives the Intent changes, and handles the Intent differently or not at all; but at least then it does so on purpose.

Comment: How can i use Intent to pass data without re-open application?

Comment: `Intent` is a one and only special AOS feature intented for tasks like you'd mention - passing a data between apps, starting other apps but NOT CONROLLING other apps. And `Toast` just shares a screen and nothing more.